# Regular Expressions, End of Line and a Bashscript will just not work together

Tags: regex, bash, shell, expression

I'm currently writing a bash script for renaming files.
Every file looks like this ***_#.ext** where * can be anything and # a 9 digits number. In this example, ill stick with 3 digits instead.

Here is a basic example of what it should do:

> Input: **example1_123.jpg**
> Output: **example1.jpg**

Simple enough? Right:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="example1_123.jpg"
echo ${filename/_[0-9][0-9][0-9]/}
```

> Output: example1.jpg

This works... as long as the input isn't something like this filename:
example2_123.jpg_987.jpg

The file will be renamed to example2.jpg_987.jpg instead of example2_123.jpg.jpg

i tried using $ for end of line, but this breaks it, as $ is used for variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="example2_123.jpg_987.jpg"
echo ${filename/_[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg$/}.${filename/*./}
```

> Output: example2_123.jpg_987.jpg.jpg
>   \$ also doesn't work. I'm clueless...

Can anyone help me getting it to work the way I need it to?

P.S. [0-9]{3} instead of [0-9][0-9][0-9] also breaks it. If someone knows how to shorten it, please say so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
target=$(echo $f | sed 's,_[0-9]\+\(\.[a-z]\+\)$,\1')
```

This will do what you want.

```
fg@erwin ~ $ f=example2_123.jpg_987.png
fg@erwin ~ $ target=$(echo $f | sed 's,_[0-9]\+\(\.[a-z]\+\)$,\1,')
fg@erwin ~ $ echo $target
example2_123.jpg.png
fg@erwin ~ $ f=example1_123.png
fg@erwin ~ $ target=$(echo $f | sed 's,_[0-9]\+\(\.[a-z]\+\)$,\1,')
fg@erwin ~ $ echo $target
example1.png
```

Surround `$(...)` with double quotes should you have space names in `$f`.

This is sed, therefore a classical regex dialect, therefore grouping, alternatives and quantifiers (well, except `*`) all need to be preceded with a backslash... The "canonical" regex really is:

```
_[0-9]+(\.[a-z]+)$
```

Comment: thanks. this worked as well, though... as i need i noticed that (jpg|png|gif) is also unsupported (probably due to |)... alternatives?

Comment: Most probably because bash uses old-style regexes. I'd use a combination of `echo | sed` really, since bash is really limited. To do what you do would need backreference support.

Answer (score 1):

$ is not used by bash, bash uses the % prefix:

```
echo ${filename/%_[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg/}.${filename/*./}
```

Comment: thanks! this is what i needed! though, as the extension isn't restricted to only jpg, i need a usable regex replacement for this as well. unfortunately, (jpg|png|gif) doesn't work and breaks again :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
filename="example2_123.jpg_987.jpg"
echo ${filename//_[0-9][0-9][0-9]/}
```

So all _NNN will be replaced. The output above is: `example2.jpg.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try `${filename%_[0-9]*.*}.${filename##*.}"` as in this example:

```
for filename in example1_123.jpg example2_123.jpg_987.jpg example2_4.jpg_1.jpg ; do
    echo "$filename -> ${filename%_[0-9]*.*}.${filename##*.}"
done
```

This will output

```
example1_123.jpg -> example1.jpg
example2_123.jpg_987.jpg -> example2_123.jpg.jpg
example2_4.jpg_1.jpg -> example2_4.jpg.jpg
```

Thus always removing the final _ followed by any digits.